# Как найти путь куда установлен npm

Tags: node.js

Мне в path моей ОС нужно прописать новый путь к npm. Это связано с вот этой ошибкой, ни одна команда не которая начинается на npm не работает.

```
npm : Имя "npm" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сц
енария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания
имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите по
пытку.строка:1 знак:1
+ npm install 9.2.0
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], Com
   mandNotFoundException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Другие версии node у меня не работают в принципе, там другие ошибки.

Куда прописать я уже знаю. А вот где найти этот путь, к какому файлу... не могу понять. Подскажите где и что искать?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, он находится где-то в %AppData%